# There is no libth_transformer.so after I build the FasterTransformer

Tags: nvidia, transformer-model

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DSM=86 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make -j20
```

After I build the FasterTransformer in WSL using the above command, there is no file named libth_transformer.so under the build/lib directory and there is no error during the building. Why?

I've tried some method found in github, but did not solve it.